# Nginx configuration doesn't work with wordpress in subdirectory

Tags: nginx, subdomain, wordpress, http-status-code-404, directory

I have a nginx installation which I need for hosting web sites in development so that other people can test them out.

Right now I've set up a virtual host for a single sub-domain and in that directory I symlink projects which should be open for testing. As you can see have I restricted access to the whole site but enabled for the specific directory, but keeping it private with a simple auth_basic.

The PHP runs but I keep getting 404s for anything other than / or /wp-admin/, all the other permalinks gives 404s. I've done just about everything to get this to work but I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Please point out my error in the following configuration:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name dev.example.com;
  client_max_body_size 20m;
  server_tokens off;

  root /srv/dev.example.com;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  location / {
    deny all;
  }

  location /my-site {
    allow all;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/auth.d/.htpasswd-my-site;

    location ~ \.php$ {
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_pass php5-fpm-sock;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
      fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
      fastcgi_param HTTPS $https;
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you!

**UPDATE:**

This request would work: `http://dev.example.com/my-site/`, it would result in loading the file `/srv/dev.example.com/my-site/index.php`.

A request to the wordpress admin interface would work too: `http://dev.example.com/my-site/wp/wp-admin`, also going directly to an index file: `/srv/dev.example.com/my-site/wp/wp-admin/index.php`. Everything within the admin interface works since it doesn't use permalinks but the raw GET input.

However, as soon as I attempt to load a permalink (I use the most simple format `/%postname%/`) it fails in finding it and the try_files directive in `location /my-site {}` should match them. This means that routes such as the following doesn't work:

```
http://dev.example.com/my-site/about
http://dev.example.com/my-site/contact
http://dev.example.com/my-site/etc
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample URL that falls in 404 and the real path on your filesystem to that resource ?

Comment: Xavier Lucas, I added the sample you asked for. Does it help?

Comment: It does, definately.

Answer (score 3):

I'm gonna assume the following files don't exist on your filesystem :

```
/srv/dev.example.com/my-site/about/index.{php,html,htm}
/srv/dev.example.com/my-site/contact/index.{php,html,htm}
/srv/dev.example.com/my-site/etc/index.{php,html,htm}
```

Your issue comes from the fact that your php fallback location is nested within `/my-site` location and that `try_files` directive may not work like you are expecting.

Indeed, `try_files` accepts as a last parameter either :

1. an URI
2. a named location
3. an HTTP code

For options 1 & 2, it will imply an **internal redirect** to the specified element. In your case `/index.php?$args` is interpreted as an URI and nginx will internaly redirect to it if `$uri`, `$uri/`, `$uri/index.php`, `$uri/index.html`, `$uri/index.htm` are missing.

Now, the other thing is : you use a nested location to handle php files processing. But as your `try_files` last parameter is the `/index.php?$args` URI it won't match the apex location `/my-site` so it's handled by the server block and if the URI can't be resolved to a local file then you end up with an HTTP 404 reply.

Note that the `index` directive will also imply internal redirects to the specified index files, but as  URIs start with `/my-site` it will always fall in your php location.

So you must either move this location to the same level than the others or prefix your `try_files` URI with the prefix of your apex location and make sure the php file is in the right place.

Comment: So what you are saying is that the try_files directive should instead be under `location / {}` or that I change the last element to `/my-site/index.php?$args`? Does it really matter where I put the `location ~ \.php$ {` since I'm not getting "File not found" from php-fpm but 404 from nginx? Are you also saying that I can't have the try_files directive under the `location /my-site {}`, that it must be at the root?

Comment: @Niklas Well, I though I had explained these. Either change the last parameter of try_files or move the php location to the same level than the other locations. The 404 from nginx is exactly what I explained : you don't reach the php location because it's nested in `/my-site` and the URI of `/index.php?$args` doesn't match `/my-site` location.